# php Multidimensional Array - Undefined offset / index

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that holds a number of arrays. I access them in turn e.g.

`print_r($orderData[0])` and the output is:

```
Array (
  [201] => Array (
    [name] => SuperMarket One
    [type] => line_item
    [item_meta] => Array (
      [_qty] => Array (
        [0] => 1
      )
    )
  )
)
```

My issue is, I can't seem to access anything e.g. `print_r($orderData[0]['name'])` gives me:

```
Notice: Undefined index: name in /Path
```

Likewise, I can't use `print_r($orderData[0][0])` etc.

I must be missing something quite obvious here.

Comment: You can access like this: $orderData[0][201]['name']

Answer (score 1):

You have another array in it with the key 201. Use PHP's function  **var_dump($orderData[0])** to view the complete structure of your array.

Answer (score 0):

Access it using

```
$orderData[0][201]['name']
```

Comment: Can you explain why the 201 is there? And not: $orderData[0][0]['name']?

Comment: 201 is the first inner index of your array. So you can access it using that index.